# What does the processAjaxOnInit option in tablesorter do?

Tags: ajax, tablesorter

I have used this option in the pager widget (so I used `pager_processAjaxOnInit: false`), but can't tell that it has an effect. I thought  it might cause the ajaxProcessing option to not run upon initial loading of the table, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states:

> Set this option to false if your table data is preloaded into the table, but you are still using ajax (New v2.14.5).

For more details see [issue #424](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/424).

Comment: Yes, noticed that, but I'm still getting an ajax call after the table initially loads, so it sounds like this is not working for me.

Comment: Ok, please open an issue, so I can track and investigate this problem.